# What does "I just am not big" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm not a native English speaker. Maybe you can help me with this sentence, I just want to know, what does it mean?

> I just am **not big on** tucking my shirt in or ironing it or shaving.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we as a group do not purport to be experts on the Spanish Language, only on the English Language, and so requests for advice for translating into Spanish fall outside of our remit.

Comment: @tchrist I know, not a problem I just wanna know the definition of that sentence and the answer was good, but anyway thanks.

Comment: *Be big on* should be findable in any English dictionary worthy of the name. How you wish to translate that casual expression into a corresponding Spanish one will depend on the tone you are trying to convey and on which particular regional version of Spanish you’re aiming for.

Answer (score 5):

"I am not that big on..." means I am not very enthusiastic about doing something.

This is the North American version of the expression. In England you would say "I am not (that) keen on..."